# how to print bitmap on condition?

Tags: c++, winapi

please help me to print bitmap on condition.
i have two buttons created as

```
    case WM_CREATE:
    HWND button1,button2;

    button1= CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("button1"),              
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP|BS_FLAT,
             675, 720, 105, 35,  
             hwnd, (HMENU) pgn, NULL, NULL);
    button2=CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("button2"),              
           WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP|BS_FLAT,
           675, 720, 105, 35,  
           hwnd, (HMENU) pgn, NULL, NULL);
```

and two images loaded as:

```
    HBITMAP img1,img2;
    static HINSTANCE g_hInst=NULL;
    img1 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst,"a100");
    img2 = LoadBitmsp(g_hInst,"a101");
```

i want to print img1 when button1 is pressed and print img2 when button2 is pressed. i used the following code:

```
    BITMAP bm;

    case WM_CREATE:
    GetObject(img1, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    case WM_COMMAND:

    switch (wParam)
    {
         case pgn:
         PAINTSTRUCT ps;
         HDC hdcWindow;
         hdcWindow = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
         HDC hdcMemory;
         hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);


         SelectObject(hdcMemory, img1);
         BitBlt(hdcWindow, 150,25,900, bm.bmHeight, hdcMemory, 0, 0,SRCCOPY);

         DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
         EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);     
         break; 

    case pgp:

    hdcWindow = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);


    SelectObject(hdcMemory,img2);
    BitBlt(hdcWindow, 150,25,900, bm.bmHeight, hdcMemory, 0, 0,SRCCOPY);

    DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

but it work for only for first button press. i want to print img1 when button1 is pressed and print img2 when button2 is pressed. Can i get a better code. can any one help me.
thanks.

Comment: Create code responsible for processing buttons and act accordingly. It isn't particularly hard, unless you're aiming for more generic "n buttons" thing or something.

Comment: What aspect of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: The action only continue for the first attempt.

Comment: Why you call BeginPaint in the WM_COMMAND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a variable indicating which bitmap should be shown.

```
HBITMAP hbmpSelected = NULL;
```

When you get a button press, change the variable and call InvalidateRect.  That will cause your message loop to dispatch and WM_PAINT handler.

```
// in WM_COMMAND handler
case pgn:
    hbmpSelected = img1;
    InvalidateRect(HWND, NULL);
    break;
case pgp:
    hbmpSelected = img2;
    InvalidateRect(HWND, NULL);
    break;
```

Put all your painting code in the handler for WM_PAINT.  That code should check the variable to decide which bitmap to select into the memory DC before blitting it to the window.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdcWindow = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    if (hbmpSelected != NULL) {
        HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
        HGDIOBJ hbmpOld = SelectObject(hdcMemory, hbmpSelected);
        BitBlt(hdcWindow, 150, 25, 900, bm.bmHeight, hdcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hdcMemory, hbmpOld);
        DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
    }
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
```

(In particular, only use BeginPaint and EndPaint inside a WM_PAINT handler.  There are ways to paint to your window in other places, but that's only for exceptional circumstances and you wouldn't use BeginPaint/EndPaint for that kind of painting.)

(Also be sure to select your bitmap back out of the memory DC before destroying the memory DC.  Modern versions of GDI tend to tolerate bugs like this, but it's best to clean up directly.)

(Also note that your buttons are created with the same ID, pgn.  I assume that's a transcription error and that the second one should be pgp.)